# The web server hangs while calling 3rd party Web API from my Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I need to call a 3 party Web Api from my ASP.net Web API, when it runs the line

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/ArTrx/postDocument", poMaster);
```

the web server hangs. I have tried to put below code in to a console program, it runs well. What is wrong with below code when run in ASP.net Web API project?

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(webAPIAddress);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

string token = Crypto.EncryptStringAES("abcd1234");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Token", token);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/ArTrx/postDocument", poMaster);    
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a `Task<T>.Result` or `Task.Wait` call further up your call stack. This will [cause a deadlock on ASP.NET](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I describe in more detail on my blog.

In summary, `await` will capture a "context" - in this case, an ASP.NET request context, which only allows one running thread at a time. When its awaitable completes (that is, when the POST finishes), the `async` method will continue *in that context*. If your code is blocking further up the call stack (e.g., `Result` or `Wait`), then it will block a thread in that ASP.NET request context, and the `async` method cannot enter that context to continue executing.

You don't see the deadlock in the Console app because there's no context being captured, so the `async` method resumes on a thread pool thread instead.

Comment: I'm reading your helpful article but I'm wondering if you can tell me off-the-top-of-your-head: do you know if the _in context_ applies to Azure (continuous) Web Jobs and Azure Functions, especially the former since they are kinda console apps. I've also found this [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#use-async-code-but-avoid-blocking-calls) that seems to suggest that it does apply to Azure Functions.

Comment: @gabe: I don't know about Web Jobs. The easiest way to tell is to break-and-inspect (or debug-print) the value of `SynchronizationContext.Current` and `TaskScheduler.Current.GetType().Name`. If they are `null` and `TaskScheduler`, respectively, then there is no context.